# Why does my colorscheme sometimes get all messed in GVIM on Windows 10?

Tags: vim, gvim, color-theme, vimscript, solarized

I have recently added the following code to `$MYGVIMRC` (which otherwise has been unchanged for years and has been working fine) to have my GVIM (8.2) on Windows 10 switch background automatically depending on the time of day:

```
fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
    let hour = strftime('%H')
    let value = ((hour > 6 && hour < 18) ? 'light' : 'dark')
    if !(value == &background)
        let &background = value
    endif
endfun
call timer_start(15 * 60 * 1000, function('s:set_bg'), { 'repeat': -1 })
call s:set_bg(0)
```

It works fine except that in the condition when the PC wakes back from sleep, the Solarized color scheme I am normally running, has colors all messed up. This wasn't happening before I added the above code (which has `s:set_bg` called every 15 minutes, as you can see, to evaluate whether background needs switching), but then again nothing ran periodically at all before I added it, here is the contents of the `$MYGVIMRC`:

```
set guicursor=a:blinkoff200-blinkon2000
set guifont=Iosevka_Term:h14
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=l
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=R
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=t
set renderoptions=type:directx

colorscheme solarized

fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
    let hour = strftime('%H')
    let value = ((hour > 6 && hour < 18) ? 'light' : 'dark')
    if !(value == &background)
        let &background = value
    endif
endfun
call timer_start(15 * 60 * 1000, function('s:set_bg'), { 'repeat': -1 })
call s:set_bg(0)
```

It must be noted that both the buffers I tend to keep open in GVIM, *and* my `$MYGVIMRC` *and* the color scheme definition file (`solarized.vim`), are on a network mounted volume (network drive), with the network being briefly unavailable after waking up the PC because the organization administering the Windows domain has Direct Access (a VPN) enabled, which takes some time to reconnect the aforementioned network drive.

Can anyone provide any assistance on what may be happening here -- why my color scheme gets messed up? I would imagine the fact that the network drive is briefly unavailable shouldn't have anything to say since at least `$MYGVIMRC` is loaded once on startup and all the script it contains is kept in memory since?

Comment: Is your colorscheme also on the network drive? If so, you might want to write a check in your code to make sure the file exists and is readable at the time it switches.

Comment: Yes, it is -- and it just struck me that it's what may be causing this problem. Either that or what [romainl's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1651660/29051) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to change the whole third-party colorscheme when the value of `:help 'background'` changes is a hack that conflicts with another built-in hack that purports to adjust the default colorscheme to the terminal emulator's background color.

My hypothesis is that, due to network lag, `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim` is sourced after whatever your colorscheme uses to listen to `&background` changes is executed, and thus overrides some of your colorscheme's styles.

Comment: So the whole `set background` thing used by Solarized, basically relies on a hack, and the fact that my color scheme (and/or assets) served over network (which may be briefly unavailable at times around switching of background) relies on said hack, all translate to the unreliable result I am observing? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: You did, but that's just a hypothesis. I wouldn't touch solarized with a ten foot pole and I don't have a network drive at hand so I can't prove it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Why would you not touch Solarized with a 10-foot pole, if I may ask -- does it have to do with the colors themselves or is it about how the scheme is implemented for Vim? I am just curious -- I have little understanding of how color schemes are supposed to be idiomatically implemented in Vim.

Comment: The technical side of that colorscheme is a train wreck and some of the technical issues can be tracked to poor design choices. It is not as popular now as it used to be (and it is mostly abandoned anyway) but there was a time when Vim (and others) support channels were literally flooded with Solarized questions. Whether one likes the colors or not is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable assistance and opinion.